# Object to specific Enum conversion with generic type class

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, type-conversion

I have several Enums that I am displaying at the View as selection in several ComboBoxes. I am using a converter to get display names from a cached attribute dictionary. There are no issues when I explicitly cast the object coming into the converter as a specific Enum (I use the parameter object and a switch to figure out which Enum to explicitly cast) however, I want to make this control more generic and usable for any Enum based property I bind in at the View.

Here's what I tried at the converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(value.GetType()) ?? value.GetType();
        var item = System.Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
        return item.GetEnumDisplayName();
    }
    else
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
}
```

Here's the cache dictionary object:

```
public static class EnumDisplayCache<T> //where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    private static Dictionary<T, string> _cache;

    static EnumDisplayCache()
    {
        _cache = new Dictionary<T, string>();
        Type type = typeof(T);
        foreach (T e in Enum.GetValues(type).Cast<T>())
            _cache.Add(e, e.GetDisplayName());
    }

    public static string GetDisplayName(T value)
    {
        return _cache[value];
    }
}
```

The extension method for "GetEnumDisplayName" is not shown, but it just passes `T` to the cache dictionary.

This is the Exception:

> Type provided must be an Enum.

How can I cast that object into its original Enum? When I step through the code in the debugger, the type appears to be correct in the converter.

Updated with the extension method(s):

```
internal static string GetDisplayName<T>(this T enumValue) //where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
        return enumValue.GetType()?
                        .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())?
                        .First()?
                        .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?
                        .GetName() ?? enumValue.ToString();
}

public static string GetEnumDisplayName<T>(this T value) //where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
{
    return EnumDisplayCache<T>.GetDisplayName(value);
}
```

Update with XAML and ViewModel:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleDimensions}"
                           SelectedItem="{Binding Dimensionality, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource enumToDisplayConverter}, 
                                                         ConverterParameter='dimensionality'}" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      </ComboBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

ViewModel:

```
public List<Dimensionality> PossibleDimensions { get { return _possibleDimensions; } }
private static List<Dimensionality> _possibleDimensions;
public Dimensionality Dimensionality
{
    get { return (DataContext as Analog).Dimensionality; }
    set
    {
        if (value != (DataContext as Analog).Dimensionality)
        {
            (DataContext as Analog).Dimensionality = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Dimensionality"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The bug is in `GetEnumDisplayName`, could you show that code?

Comment: Updated with the extension methods.

Comment: Your code appears to work well; I can't re-create the error. In what situation, and where exactly, are you getting this exception?

Comment: I'm getting the exception at the `foreach` loop in the EnumDisplayCache object. The binding on my combobox is to a property that is an enum. I'll update the question with the xaml and the object.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because the `System.Convert.ChangeType` method that you call in your converter returns an `object` and not a `Dimensionality`. So you are actually calling `object.GetEnumDisplayName` instead of `Dimensionality.GetEnumDisplayName`.

If you uncomment out the type constraints you will see this clearer as the code won't even compile.

If you get rid of the non-working cache, your extensions methods will work though:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    internal static string GetDisplayName<T>(this T enumValue) //where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    {
        return enumValue.GetType()?
                        .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())?
                        .First()?
                        .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?
                        .GetName() ?? enumValue.ToString();
    }

    public static string GetEnumDisplayName<T>(this T value) //where T : struct, IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
    {
        return GetDisplayName(value);
    }
}
```

But you will have to call the `GetType()` method to get the *runtime type* of the current enum value. It's either that or casting the result of `System.Convert.ChangeType` to a specific enum type. There is nothing "generic" about enum types.

Comment: So you're saying it is not possible to use the cache without explicitly casting to an enum?

Comment: Yes, you can't use the generic EnumDisplayCache class like this.